Fatal error: glibc. Trying to put char in file
I'm trying to put and get+print four char characters in a file by promting the user for four chars. However, there is an error (Fatal error: glibc detected an invalid stdio handle).
After debugging I found the fault at the line fputc(c[3], putc). After prompting the user for the fourth time, it cannot put the fourth char c[3] in the file.
Please help me to understand.
Here's my code:
    FILE* putc = fopen("test3.txt", "w");

    if(putc == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char c[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("char: ");
        scanf("%s", &c[i]);
        fputc(c[i], putc);
    }


    fclose(putc);

    FILE* getc = fopen("test3.txt", "r");

    if(getc == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char abc;

    while ((abc = fgetc(getc)) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", abc);
    }
    printf("\n");

    fclose(getc);


I don't know if it's the cause of trouble, but the file stream names putc and getc are treading on thin ice; they are also function names.

scanf("%s", &c[i]); That's wrong. What do you want this to do?

@TomKarzes: If they are implemented as macros, they are function-like macros and will not affect the uses of getc and putc in this code.

@TomKarzes: It will not affect the code because an identifier for a function-like macro is not macro-replaced if it is not immediately followed by a left parentheses. The source tokens in this case are unchanged. There will be no effect on OP’s code. In this respect, OP’s code is portable and strictly conforming as defined by the C standard.

@EricPostpischil Ok, yes, if the identifiers are not followed by parentheses, then I guess it's safe.  I still consider it very bad, but yeah, I think you're right.

scanf("%s", &c[i]) writes a null character after the input it reads and stores. c is defined with only four elements, so, when i is three, the null character is written outside of the array c, corrupting other memory in the program.
One fix is to make c larger and scan with scanf("%1s", &c[i]).
Another is to scan with scanf(" %c", &c[i]), to skip spaces and read a single character, which is put into c[i] with no terminating null character.

I don't encounter errors with gcc version "Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04", compiled with command $ gcc -Wall -o foo foo.c.  What version of gcc do you have, and how are you invoking the compiler/linker?
What input are you providing?  From the debugger, examine the contents of the array c[].
As an aside, I suggest that choose different variable names for putc and getc, both are C standard library functions.
From man putc:

putc() is equivalent to fputc() except that it may be implemented as a
macro which evaluates stream more than once.

From man getc:

getc() is equivalent to fgetc() except that it may be implemented as a
macro which evaluates stream more than once.

Also, I wouldn't use scanf(); it's generally a bad idea.  See this explanation of safer alternatives.

I used VSCODE. I have solved it by using 'scanf(" %c", &c[i]). Putting a space before '%s' seemed to work. Not using scanf altogether also worked.
